# Check Series label does not exist in a separate DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm iterating over two separate dataframes, where one dataframe is a subset of the other. I need to ensure that *only* the columns in the set (df1) which are not contained in the subset (df2) pass the conditional statement.

In this case, it would be comparing the Series object during each iteration in df1 to the dataframe, df2. Ideally I would like to compare just the labels associated with each column, not the values contained in the columns. My code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```py
for i in df1:
    for j in df2:
        if df1[i] is not in df2:

            ...do some stuff between df1[i] and df2[j]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out if the values of df1 are in df2 you can use:

```
df1.isin(df2)
```

To find all values in df1 that are not in df2 you can use:

```
df1[~df1.isin(df2)]
```

The values that are in df1 and df2 will be a `nan` in this case

Comment: Thanks for the response @peter! For clarification, will this return a new dataframe containing the disjoint subset between df1 and df2?

Comment: @ThomasTownsley You're welcome. ~df1.isin(df2) returns a dataframe the size of df1, which has False on all locations where df1 is equal to df2 and True on al locations where df1 is not equal to df2. If this answer solved your problem, can you mark it as accepted? Thanks in advance

Comment: Done! Thanks for the help!